# Two graphic cards same power cable 8 and 6+2

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I`m planning to add another graphics card to my computer.

I have rx 570 and it requires a 8 pin power connector.
I have a power cable that has 8 (used by graphics card) and 6+2, so if I understood well 6+2 can be used as 6 or 8.

I will add another rx 570 and I`m not sure if the 8 and 6+2 power cable will give enoght juice for both.

PSU is a Corsair 650W, which powered a r9 290x before ( consuming the same as 2 rx 570 ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is enough. 6+2 is the same as 8-pin, no difference whatsoever. The extra wires are actually to distribute the current in order to prevent overheating of wires. Assuming you can have wires with thicker diameter, you could use less of them with the same result.

As for the PSU, the provided power will be enough for those cards, even if you would use something like 8+ hard-drives.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, those connectors (6+2 & 8 Pin) deliver the same amount of power.
2. I looked up the reference design, so it may vary with your cards, and they consume maximum 300W (together) power so your 650W PSU should be enough. I still recommend you to go to an online power consumption calculator, where you can enter all your components and calculate the total power consumption and a fitting PSU.